# PHP method class variable

Tags: php

is it possible set method variable default value if variable is expected to be "new class"

```
class controller{

    function getData(client $client){
    }
}

$c = new controller;
$c->getData( new client );
```

TO SET DEFAULT VALUE LIKE

```
class controller{

    function getData(client $client = new client){
    }
}

$c = new controller;
$c->getData();
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. You should implement this behaviour in the method:

```
class controller{

    function getData(client $client = null){
        if (is_null($client)) {
            $client = new client;
        }
    }
}
```